# SearchView onMenuItemActionCollapse Not Working

Tags: android, searchview

I'm using `SearchView` while my activity is extanding **Sherlock Library.**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.countriesxml, menu);
        SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchall)
                .getActionView();
        mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search for smartphones");
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchall);

menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            item.collapseActionView();
            indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lvth.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
    });

    return;
}
```

Please note that i tried to use OnCloseListener() but it didn't work.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at your code at this section:

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
```

Replace it with below code and try again.

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using OnFocusChangeListener instead

```
    menuItem.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean queryTextFocused) {
            if (!queryTextFocused) {
                // Code here
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think that's a proper solution