# How do i detect when the back button on an Android action layout is tapped?

Tags: android, menu

I'm making an Android app that allows the user to search a collection of information. I begin by displaying the collection, but when a search button in the actionbar is tapped, an action layout (search bar) shows in the action bar. When a search is conducted, the listview information is replaced with information from the query. However, when a user taps the back arrow button next to the search bar, I would like to replace the queried information with the original information.

**Is there any way to detect when the back arrow button is tapped next to the search bar? Thank you very much for your help!**

Menu XML

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="">
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/some_layout"
/>
</menu>
```

Activity Code: trying this: [SearchView onMenuItemActionCollapse Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869445/searchview-onmenuitemactioncollapse-not-working)
but keep getting a Null Pointer Exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to detect it indeed. First thing that came up to me was the following: create a boolean with false as default value. Whenever you query for specific search results, you turn the boolean to the true. When the 'back arrow' *(navigation up)* button has been pressed, you check whether the boolean turns out to be true. If it's true, it means that the app doesn't show you the original information set and shouldn't close your activity.

For example (from Google docs, partly.):

```
public boolean originalContentReplaced = false;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        if(originalContentReplaced) {
            // Do what you need to do here to get the original content back.
            this.originalContentReplaced = false;
        } else {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            // You could also use onBackPressed().
        }

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I don't know how you query your new search results but when your search is successful, you should change `originalContentReplaced` variable to true.

You could use the very same if-else statement when you press on the hardware back button. Anyway, this should give you a very clear idea on how to detect when the navigation up/back arrow button is pressed. :)

Comment: Thank you for the response! This sounds PERFECT, however, it doesn't look like 'android.R.id.home' is called when the up/back arrow button is pressed while the search bar is active :/ any way around this?

Comment: I found out that I need to implement onMenuItemActionCollapse,  but cannot find any working examples...

Comment: From what I understand is that you up/back arrow button doesn't properly work when the search bar in the actionbar is currently being used? Otherwise it just works if the search bar is not active?

Comment: when loading the activity, the up/back arrow works fine. However, after tapping the search icon (which displays the search bar), I am unable to detect another tap on the up/back arrow (which simply hides the search bar)

Comment: Could you edit your question with your Activity source code and the content of the menu.xml that includes the search button? That would be a major help. I already have it figured out in my head but I rather work it out with the code that you already have and I will edit my answer once it proper works.